# Checking if the specific key is pressed on a looping function

Tags: javascript, html

So my script has a looping function that is designed to print out a string when a specific key (the a key) is pressed down, and if its not then it prints out a different string, so that when the key is held it will continuously print the first string. I have tried about 30 different ways to make it register but nothing will work. The function begins running from another function, NOT when I press the button on a div so I don't want to hear any onKeyDown to run this function, I need it constantly running and checking when the key is pressed

```
function legs(interval, key, text) {

    if (foot == true) {
        text.innerHTML = 'Left Foot<br/><br/>' + text.innerHTML;
    } else {
        text.innerHTML = 'Trip!<br/><br/>' + text.innerHTML;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){legs(interval, key, text)},interval);
}
```

The interval its passed to with is 500, the key is 'a', and the text is the div that its printing the string out to. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean variable `keyPressed`. Use a keydown event on the document to watch for the `a` key. If it's pressed, change the variable `keyPressed = true`. Then set `keyPressed = false` on keyup.

**Using jQuery:**

```
var keyPressed = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        //if a key is held down
        if(keycode == 65){
            keyPressed = true;
        }


    });

$(document).keyup(function(e){
        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if(keycode == 65){
            keyPressed = false;
        }
    });
```

**Using plain ol' JavaScript:**

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        //if a key is held down
        if(keycode == 65){
            keyPressed = true;
        }


    }

document.onkeyup = function(e){
        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if(keycode == 65){
            keyPressed = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that your solution depends on jQuery, this is not bad but you probably should mention it.

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt, good point. I've added a non-jQuery version as well.

Comment: This refuses to work. I've copied the exact code to my script, only changing the 'keyPressed' variable to 'foot' but it refuses to do anything, as well as the main function printing the lines will not print either now so I'm thinking this function broke it in some form

EDIT: I had to change the document.onkeyup(function to document.body.onkeyup = function. Works now, thanks

Comment: Yeah, I just caught that. I've updated the answer to reflect those changes. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `isAKeyDown` flag, like this:

```
var isAKeyDown;
```

Then add an onkeydown handler where you check if the key pressed is the A key, if so set isAKeyDown to true. In the onkeyup handler set it to false again.